# how to install gradle in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin, build.gradle

i want use gradle in eclipse luna,
i try the method searched from stackoverflow,help->install new software

```
http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle
```

bu i can't get the repsitory,error logs

```
Unable to read repository at file:/home/yangjun/develop/eclipse /p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache/compositeContent-1934502244.xml
Unable to read repository at file:/home/yangjun/develop/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache/compositeContent-1934502244.xml
The end-tag for element type "frame" must end with a '>' delimiter.
```

whatt'is wrong

Answer (score 0):

@yang is your luna updated to version 4.4.? else get it updated from http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44#.VB_gPGOMl40

And try installing the plugin from http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/